# "I started watching TV after I have finished my homework" vs "I started watching TV after I finished my homework"

Tags: meaning

"I started watching TV after I have finished my homework" or "I started watching TV after I finished my homework" ? Is there any difference at all ?

Comment: The first sentence is not correct, at least not without a time machine.  "Started watching" happened in the past, and "after I have finished" is in the future.

Answer (score 3):

"I started watching TV after I had finished my homework."  In this case, you want to use the past participle.  It is also common to hear "I started watching TV after I finished my homework."  Those are really the only correct ones.  Because you are saying that you **started** watching TV, you wouldn't be able to say "have finished."

If you are talking about your general routine, it would be okay to say, "I start watching TV after I have finished my homework" or "after I finish my homework."